# custom validation query always fires - express validator

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to implement validation using express validator that should only kick in if the field actually has some input. If it is empty it should just be ignored. The first part of the validation if the field is to check to check it meets the regex requirements and the second check is to see if the value exists in the database. Lower case versions of the same username with capital letters are not allowed ie: Shirley and shirley are seen as the same thing.

```
body('username')
    .trim()
    .custom((value, { req }) => {
        var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,20}$/;
        if (value != '' && !value.match(regex)) {
            throw new Error('Username does not meet required criteria.');
        }
        return true;
    })
    .custom((value, { req }) => {
        if (value !== '') {
            return User.findOne({ username: new RegExp(`^${value}$`, 'i') })
                .then(userDoc => {
                    if (userDoc) {
                        return Promise.reject('Username unavailable');
                    }
                    return true;
                });
        }
    }),
```

If I leave the username field empty I still get a validation error telling me 'username unavailable'

Comment: So... you have a condition based on `value` being not loosly equal to `<empty string>`. What exactly *is* the value of `value` in that situation? surely that'd be the first thing you tested.

Comment: @KevinB, if I console.log value I get nothingness, just a blank line in my visual studio code terminal, so it is empty.

Comment: Sorry, yeah. I was looking at my old version which was `if(value)`

Comment: @KevinB, I added some code to check and in console I get the message: ""value is empty". `if (value !== '') {
                    console.log('the value is not empty');
                } else if (value === '') {
                    console.log('value is empty');
                }`

Comment: does the callback passed to custom need to have a return value? (where are the docs?)

Comment: @KevinB, here you go. https://express-validator.github.io/docs/custom-validators-sanitizers.html

Comment: Yea, your code looks fine to me then. Are you sure the server's running with that code?

Comment: Good news, but then why doesn't it work?

Comment: @KevinB. Yes, 100% sure. It is running on my local machine. I also did hard reset of browser.

Comment: Can you change the error message?

Comment: @KevinB, sure. I changed it to 'Username is not available' and that is what I see when I submit the form

Comment: @KevinB, do you think it is because my html looks like this? `<input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="">`

Comment: that looks fine

Comment: @KevinB That is when I view the source. My actual code is: `<input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<%= oldInput.username %>">` oldInput is coming from the controller. The funny thing is though, I just noticed that I haven't even defined username in my oldInput. `oldInput: {
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            email: '',
            contactNo: '',
            city: ''
        },` So, I am surprised I didn't get an error for putting something there that isn't even defined.

Comment: @KevinB, I did another test. If I delete the username field from the user in the database which was username: "" then I don't get that validation error. So, it seems that even with my if condition in there it is still running the db query and that is the problem. It is ignoring my if statement

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get it working like this

```
  .custom(value => {
        if (value !== '') {
            return User.findOne({ username: new RegExp(`^${value}$`, 'i') })
                .then(userDoc => {
                    if (userDoc) {
                        return Promise.reject('Username not available');
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }
                })
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    })
```